# Skip rows with empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on automating orders over WhatsApp with an Excel Sheet.

My programming experience is bare bones, so I used tutorials and other stack overflow threads to get to solutions. I have something that works, but these scripts send the full lists even if the item quantity cell is empty, which doesn't work for me.

From my understanding I need a If Else statement to do this, but I dont know where to place it.

The goal is to if a cell in the column is empty that row is skipped. How can I do that?

The below is the script that opens the browser and sends the messages.

```
Sub WebWhatsApp()

Dim pop As Range
Dim BOT As New WebDriver
Dim KS As New Keys
Dim count_row As Integer

count_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Interface").Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(count_row, 5))
Dim myString As String
myString = Rang2String(rng)

BOT.Start "chrome", "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
BOT.Get "/"

MsgBox _
              "Please scan the QR code." & _
              "After you are logged in, please confirm this message box by clicking 'ok'", vbOKOnly, "WhatsApp Bot"

searchtext = Sheets("Interface").Range(Cells(5, 8), Cells(5, 8))

textmessage = myString

BOT.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='side']/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]").Click

BOT.Wait (500)

BOT.SendKeys (searchtext)

BOT.Wait (500)

BOT.SendKeys (KS.Enter)

BOT.Wait (500)

BOT.SendKeys (textmessage)

BOT.Wait (1000)

BOT.SendKeys (KS.Enter)

MsgBox "Done."


End Sub
```

And this is the script that turns a range of the Excel sheet into a string that the main script sends out as text messages.

```
Function Rang2String(rng As Range) As String
    
Dim strng As String
Dim myRow As Range
Dim KS As New Keys
    
    With rng
        For Each myRow In .Rows
            strng = strng & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRow.Value)), " | ") & vbNewLine
        Next
    End With
    
    Rang2String = Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1)
     
End Function
```

I realize that the answer could be very obvious but I cant seem to see a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Function Rang2String(rng As Range) As String
    
    Const COL_QU = "D" ' quantity column
    Dim e As String, myrow As Range

    With Application
        For Each myrow In rng.Rows
            If Len(myrow.Cells(1, COL_QU)) > 0 Then
                Rang2String = Rang2String & e & Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(myrow)), " | ")
                e = vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
    End With
     
End Function
```